# find similar image in library to photo

Tags: image, image-processing, image-recognition

I work at a printer where we generate thumbnails of artwork for orders and store them in a folder before printing.

I'm looking for a code library that will allow us to take a photo of a printed item and look through the library of thumbnails for the design.

Just wondered if anyone knows of a library or api that could do this?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

[pHash](http://phash.org/) is one solution.

There are others but that mainly depends on your requirements: do you only want to identify identical images, if not, what types of transformations do you want to be able to capture etc.

In general you should look for near duplicate image search.

Answer (score 0):

@david-jennings there are numerous methods to look for similar images in libraries. Remember that google already does this in google images.
Your problem falls under the scope of **Content Based Image Retrieval (CBIR)**, which aims at looking for images with similarities in their content. MPEG-7 is a standard established many years ago to address these issues and the research field is very active with new techniques being developed constantly.
The main idea in CBIR is to extract some kind of a signature from an image and try to match it with all previously extracted signatures of all images in your database. Which method to use depends upon the specifics of your problem... According to your initial post I suppose that probably the use of SHIFT is going to do the work for you...
You may implement such a system using OpenCV with C/C++/Java/etc., or something more "scientific" using MATLAB.